# tfs copy folders from one team project to another

Tags: tfs, copy

I have one TFS server, with 4 team projects in it. i want to copy folders of of one team project into another team project. here's the tree:

```
TFS(Server) 
|_ A1(Team project1) 
|_ A2(Team project2) 
          |______(Folder1) 
          |______(Folder2) 
          |______(Folder3) 
          |______(Folder4) 
|_ A3(Team project3) 
|_ A4(Team project4)
```

I want to copy folders in A2 (TeamProject2) --> (Folder2) only to A1 (Team Project1).

How do I do this?

Answer (score 17):

There are several options.  It depends what you mean by "copy," and what your goals are for the two copies going forward.

1) You could use the Branch feature.  This is surely the most common pattern in software configuration management.  Speaking very broadly, it's what enabled parallel development.

2) You could use the Move feature.  It's just what it sounds like: the directories are moved from one place to another.  Their identity and history is unchanged.

3) You could copy the files on your local disk and use the Add feature.  (I *think* this is what JD's solution was trying to accomplish, albeit in a more roundabout and error-prone fashion).  I don't really see the point but it might be useful in some circumstances.

Comment: -1 for providing no real answer to the question. How should seena really do what he needs? Commands, methods, anything?

Comment: I know I'm kicking a dead horse here, but I believe the answer clearly states what sort of options are available in TFS.  There is no definitive one-way to do this.  And the commands are easily found through google.